# Is it possible to send task into pyRQ redis queue in async/await way?

Tags: python-3.x, redis, python-asyncio

Is it possible to send task into `pyRQ` redis queue in async/await way?

I'm using `tornado` framework which has support for new python `await`/`async` functionality.

Look at this example:

```
@job(`default`, connection=redis_conn)
def add(a: int, b: int):
    logger.info('Dummy adding task for {} and {}'.format(a, b))
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    return a + b
```

Now, in my `RequestHandler` I can do this:

```
add.delay(2, 3)
```

Line above produces I/O block due connectivity process with Redis. Does anyone has idea how can I change `@job` decorator into `async` version and then have lines like this:

```
await add.delay(2, 3)
```